# Relação Entre classes em Python

Tags: python, orientação-a-objetos, classes, método

Imagine que você esteja desenvolvendo um sistema para controle de uma Concessionária de
Veículos. Com isso é preciso registrar os veículos disponíveis na concessionária para venda.

a) Pense nos dados necessários e crie uma classe para representar os veículos.

b) Execute o programa criando 3 veículos diferentes e exibindo seus dados.

c) É preciso registrar a venda do veículo. Cada veículo pode conter a data da venda e uma
referência a quem comprou. Crie a classe que representa o comprador e crie um método no
veículo que realize a venda dele, informando o comprador e a data da venda.

d) Execute o programa registrando a venda de um dos veículos cadastrados.

e) Vamos melhorar o registro da venda do veículo. Cada veículo pode conter também a
referência a quem vendeu o carro. Crie a classe que representa o vendedor e modifique o
método que realiza a venda do veículo, informando também o vendedor.

f) Realize, novamente, a venda de um dos veículos cadastrados.

```
class Concessionaria:

    #Metodo Construtor
    def __init__(self):
        self.carros = carros
        self.compradores = compradores

class Veiculo(Concessionaria):

    # Metodo Construtor:
    def __init__(self, modelo, ano, preço):
        self.modelo = modelo
        self.ano = ano
        self.preço = preço
        self.vendedor = None
        self.comprador = None


class Comprador(Concessionaria):

    # Metodo Construtor
    def __init__(self, nome, cpf, dinheiro):
        self.nome = nome
        self.cpf = cpf
        self.dinheiro = dinheiro
        self.carro_proprio = None

class Vendedor(Concessionaria):

    # Metodo Construtor
    def __init__(self, nome, cpf, carro):
        self.nome = nome
        self.cpf = cpf
        self.carro = carro


# Objeto:
carro1 = Veiculo('P.G-207', 2007, 25000)
comprador1 = Comprador('Rodrigo','05063499180',30000)

# Metodos:
carro1.venda_do_comprador(comprador1, 'Rodrigo')

# Visualizção
print('MODELO',' |','ANO',' |','PREÇO')
print(carro1.modelo,'|',  carro1.ano,'|',  carro1.preço)
```

- Meu problema está no fato de não conseguir relacionar as diferentes classes para poder criar o método de compra.
- pois não consigo colocar o nome do objeto que pertence a classe comprador nos atributos do objeto da classe Veiculo

Comment: Basicamente você precisa completar as classes com os métodos para que assim você possa usar eles.

Você está tentando usar o método venda_do_comprador() que ainda não existe. Ele deveria estar dentro da classe Veiculo().

Answer (score 0):

[TL;DR](https://repl.it/@sidonduarte/venda-veiculo)

Na minha opnião o principal erro da sua abordagem está na modelagem, eu faria totalmente diferente, fiz uma adaptação para tentar preservar seu "estilo" ao máximo, para ficar mais simples desconsiderei a concessionaria.
Veja que modelei uma classe para a operação de venda e eliminei os modelos para comprador e vendedor, instanciando esses objetos da classe Pessoa.

```
class Veiculo:
    def __init__(self, modelo, ano, preco):
        self.modelo = modelo
        self.ano = ano
        self.preco = preco
        self.vendedor = None
        self.comprador = None  

class Pessoa():
    def __init__(self, nome, cpf):
       self.nome = nome
       self.cpf = cpf

class Venda():
    def __init__(self, num_nf, veiculo, comprador, vendedor, valor):
        self.nf=num_nf
        self.veiculo = veiculo
        self.comprador = comprador
        self.vendedor = vendedor
        self.valor = valor    

veiculo = Veiculo('P.G-207', 2007, 25000)
comprador = Pessoa('Rodrigo','05063499180')
vendedor = Pessoa('João','099634996690')
venda = Venda('18-450', veiculo, comprador, vendedor, 30000)

print('Dados da venda:')
print('NF: '+venda.nf, 'Veiculo: '+veiculo.modelo+'/'+str(veiculo.ano), 
'Comprador: '+venda.comprador.nome, \
  'Vendedor: '+venda.vendedor.nome, 'Valor: '+str(venda.valor), sep='\n')
```

Output:

```
Dados da venda:
NF: 18-450
Veiculo: P.G-207/2007
Comprador: Rodrigo
Vendedor: João
Valor: 30000
```

> Observação:
>
> Note que a resposta apresenta a "ideia geral", vc pode acrescentar campos e metodos nas classes para atender ao enunciado.

Veja funcionando no [repl.it](https://repl.it/@sidonduarte/venda-veiculo).